# Selenium Instagram Login

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hey guys I am beginning with Selenium Web **Scraping** and I want to Login on Instagram. but every time ther occures the error at the send_keys that "Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException - Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input"}"

Please help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Initiate the browser
browser  = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

#Open Website
browser.get('https://instagram.com')

#login
ig_phone = ""
ig_pass = ""



#cookies
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]').click()

#fill
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input').send_keys(ig_phone)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input').send_keys(ig_pass)
browser.find_element_by_xparh('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button').click()

#goon
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/div/div/button').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that out:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Initiate the browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# Open Website
browser.get('https://instagram.com')
# login
ig_phone = "asdfasdf"
ig_pass = "asdfasdgasdf"

myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")))
myElem.send_keys(ig_phone)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Password']").send_keys(ig_pass)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Log In']").click()
# goon
browser.quit()
```

add more flexible way to wait for the element

Comment: How can I make that the browser dont quit? Yeah I know but I can make it in 1 min